# Retain array value after postback in sharepoint list edit form

Tags: lookup-column, list-form

I have saved the values on the right side of multi-select lookup column in an array . When i click on "save" to save the form, the values are getting saved properly. But when i try to edit the form again, array becomes empty so the values are lost. can somebody help me how to retain those values across page postback

Thanks
Ranjani

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could technically use the SessionState for this scenario but I think you really need to be loading the saved values on edit.

What would happen if someone tried to edit the form at a later date, potentially on another computer? You would have to load the values, so you might as well do that in this instance too.